# What is the incentive for plants to add rich nutrients to food?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, fruit

As we know fruits are good sources of vitamins and minerals. What is the incentive for plants to add so much of vitamins and minerals to fruit pulp. My thought is that  seeds would need is some protection, and why waste rich nutrients and vitamins by adding it into pulp?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here? I think you should start with "what is the use of _fruits_?"

Comment: I think i found answer. It is for reproduction, so that when animals and birds eat fruit, seeds will be transported and it'll help plants to go to new regions and of course  for protection of seeds.....

Comment: Yes. And the point here is that when an animal will get more nutrients from a fruit, it will prefer that fruit over others, which will increase the chances of the fruit's seed's dispersal. Now, you should close/delete this question as it is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Not sure why it's off-topic. At any rate, OP, first separate minerals from vitamins - minerals are absorbed from the ground (see [here](http://www.mhhe.com/biosci/genbio/raven6b/graphics/raven06b/other/raven06_39.pdf) and note p. 784) while vitamins are usually synthesized by the plant's cells (see [this](http://arquivo.ufv.br/DBV/PGFVG/BVE684/htms/pdfs_revisao/trangenicos_transformacao/carotvitE.pdf) as an example). Also keep in mind that plants have no "incentive" to do anything - all reactions happen according to energetic considerations. [Seek](http://www.google.com) and you shall find.

Comment: Thank you. I'm kind of newbie for biology.  I was asking from evolution point of view, wondering why would they put so much effort in producing fruits..